# Can I move a running application to a different X server?

Tags: ssh, xorg, xforwarding

Is there any way to open a graphical program (for instance, gedit) while using X11 forwarding over SSH and transfer the X server connection back to the X server on the SSH host?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you look at the Wikipedia page on the subject there are several apps mentioned.

#### [Xmove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmove)

*excerpt*

> xmove is a computer program that allows the movement of X Window
>   System applications between different displays and the persistence of
>   X applications across X server restarts.[4] It solves a problem in the
>   design of X, where an X client (an X application) is tied to the X
>   server (X display) it was started on for its lifetime. Also, if the X
>   server is shut down, the client application is forced to stop running.
>
> xmove lets the client disconnect from its current X server, and
>   connect to a new one, at any time. The transition is completely
>   transparent to the client. xmove works by acting as a proxy between
>   the client and server. It is a "pseudoserver" which stores enough
>   server state so that clients can connect to a new server without being
>   disrupted.

#### [Xpra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpra)

*excerpt*

> xpra or X Persistent Remote Applications is a tool which allows you to
>   run X clients usually on a remote host and then direct their display
>   to your local machine without losing any state.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmove)
>
> It differs from standard X forwarding in that it allows disconnection
>   and reconnection without disrupting the forwarded application. It
>   differs from VNC and similar remote display technologies in that xpra
>   is rootless: i.e., applications forwarded by xpra appear on your
>   desktop as normal windows managed by your window manager, rather than
>   being all "trapped in a box together". Xpra also uses a custom
>   protocol that is self-tuning and relatively latency-insensitive, and
>   thus is usable over worse links than standard X.

#### [Guievict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guievict)

*excerpt*

> guievict is a computer program which enables the GUI of any
>   application for XFree86 implementation of X Window to be transparently
>   migrated to or replicated on another display. Unlike some program
>   providing similar functionalities, it requires neither prearranging
>   steps such as re-linking the application program binary nor
>   re-directing the application process's window system communication
>   through a proxy like xmove does.
>
> Guievict is based on a small X server extension that enables an
>   application to retrieve its window state from the X server and a
>   library of GUI migration functionality that is injected in the
>   application process at run time. Code injection or runtime
>   code-patching can be done via the DynInst API. However, guievict
>   contains its own implementation to avoid requiring users to install
>   DynInst.

Of the 3 of these, Guievict sounds like what you're looking for, mainly that it can checkpoint the state of X application AppX and migrate it to another X server where it can be restored.

Comment: slamdunk man. i wonder how that last one is pronounced. i'll upvote it again if you can link to an audible pronunciation guide...

Comment: @mikeserv - it stands for GUI Eviction - http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zandy/guievict/. gui-vict or goo-e-vict. README is here: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zandy/guievict/README.

Comment: but I cant really upvote it again, you know.

Comment: @mikeserv - I know, I didn't know how to say it either, so I looked it up.

Comment: of course you know - better than I! this is a really good answer though. you did a good job - thanks, @slm.